# Is there a non-Adobe equivalent of Axiis?

Tags: data-visualization, axiis

I want something like [Axiis](http://www.axiis.org/index.html), but without using Flex or other Adobe products.

Comment: it looks like you didn't find on that suits your needs in the list

Comment: was the answer auto-accepted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the [JavaScript InfoVis Toolkit](http://thejit.org/). Also, maybe the [gRaphaël](http://g.raphaeljs.com/) charting library (built on top of [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/)) can suit your needs.

Others:

- [Ajax.org](http://www.ajax.org/)
- [Google Chart API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/)
- [flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/)
- [Style Chart](http://chart.inetsoft.com/)
- [Bluff](http://bluff.jcoglan.com/)
- [JS Charts](http://www.jscharts.com/)
- [jqPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/)
- [pChart](http://pchart.sourceforge.net/)
- [ExtJS](http://www.extjs.com/products/extjs/#sample-4)
- [Vizualize](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_visualize_plugin_accessible_charts_graphs_from_tables_html5_canvas/)
- [TufteGraph](http://xaviershay.github.com/tufte-graph/)
- [milkchart](http://code.google.com/p/milkchart/)
- [DojoX Data Chart](https://user.sitepen.com/~mwilcox/Chart/DataChart.html)
- [jQChart](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jQchart)
- [PlotKit](http://www.liquidx.net/plotkit/)

See whether one of these suits your needs best.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I can think off the top off my head is [Google Visualization API](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/)

Of course, AFAIK, this will only work for on-line applications. And is Google any less evil than Adobe is a question for you to decide :)

Comment: Are you kidding me? Google is several orders of magnitude less evil than Adobe.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty open question, as you havent specified any preference for any particular technology or language.

I do a lot of WPF/C# stuff so I immediately start looking on that stack. Assuming that this would be a suitable platform, then [Visifire](http://www.visifire.com/) might be worth looking at... I originally found them [here](http://www.codeplex.com/visifire) on codeplex.

There seem to be a ton of third party paid for components that can do similar things. [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com) has some visualization tools that may also be worth having a look at.

Is thre any specific scenario that you are looking at, or any specific language? I think we may be able to suggest better alternatives if that was provided.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [protovis](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/) (JavaScript), looks quite similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jqChart - HTML5 jQuery Chart  Plugin](http://www.jqchart.com)